# urllib2 / requests does not display iframe of the webpage

Tags: python, iframe, beautifulsoup, urllib2, python-requests

I'm trying to scrap some book data from www.amazon.in

http://www.amazon.in/Life-What-Make-Preeti-Shenoy/dp/9380349300/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1424652069&sr=1-6

I need the summary of that book which is located in an iframe, but the problem is that when I try to use 'requests' to open that url it does not contain iframe in it.

for example, when I do

```
bookPage = requests.get(bookURL).text
bookSoup = BeautifulSoup(bookPage, "lxml")
```

There is no iframe in bookPage, but the actual page contains it.

I've also tried it with urllib2 but it does not seem to work.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the book summary from the `noscript` tag located in the `div` element with `id="bookDescription_feature_div"`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> response = requests.get('http://www.amazon.in/Life-What-Make-Preeti-Shenoy/dp/9380349300/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1424652069&sr=1-6',
...                         headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36'})
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
>>> print soup.select('div#bookDescription_feature_div noscript')[0].get_text(strip=True)
Ankita Sharma has the world in her palms. She is young, smart and heads turn at every corner she walks by. Born into a conservative middle class household - this defines the chronicle of her life. Set in a time when Doordarshan was the prime source of entertainment and writing love letters was the general fad, every youngster dreams of the thrills of college life. And so, her admission into an MBA institute in Mumbai follows. Ankita's story begins here, from her life as a college student. Life seems all sunshine and flowers until a drastic turn leaves her staring at a disturbing path, only because of her own misdoing. Jump to six months later. The sun glistens on a sombre building. Magnetized in view, the words - “Mental Institute”. Who is the face staring out of the window?What if destiny twisted your journey? What if it dragged you to a place that houses your worst fears? Would you stand and fight or would you run? Set in the late eighties, across two cities, Life is What You Make It is a compelling account of growing up, determination, faith and how an unconquerable spirit can overcome the punches destiny throws at you. At its core, it is a love story that makes us question our identity and the concept of sanity.
```

Comment: Thanks!
Not sure how I missed that.